# Broken Image icon instead video on raspberry pi motion

Tags: pi-2, motion

I fresh installed [Rasbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/) and [Motion](https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion) on my Raspberry and can see the Motion HTML interface in the browser via http.

**But instead of the video there is a broken image icon.**

Update: I try the command `raspistill -o cam.jpg` and get that error message:

**Camera control callback cmd=0x4f525245mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board**

Maybe i have to buy [a new cam](https://www.ebay.de/itm/184916988328?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item2b0de951a8:g:b0kAAOSwWTJbn3fz&amdata=enc%3AAQAGAAACoPYe5NmHp%252B2JMhMi7yxGiTJkPrKr5t53CooMSQt2orsS7UXID%252BRPOSNsnm8kYPghtDb2aXpktqaQjoZnWOLkuELak4QTJp%252F8Fmz5xYNJNuxPLLdITtDSoLbOxVlwP%252BH5yDdaRyVJFHVFkpylD87qmZHGiFE8kBETbKMocFhQZUltF3k1U0Cqwgfgw5Z1sRbOv6pw29fownFT8M5gqZIOEFXtoG%252Fm0iFSCzSvGJD86eqCfi1hlD0A%252B0TqkVvCtZZ7eI9%252FHyCUz6wu3HLqSkh99a1NEvvN0gJy0IFQ3%252Fk5BiicryUoAS6K%252B2qnTRn70WKAOKrvqyvoforgORTiCwSyY9dH%252BNCgrUeIH46TSeXDM7DTzUTCWoNpW7X2d9eUPmH7Ir9yfeePD7h%252F%252FP3dWV6hPwqVDPz8ID3ESX64Z0uoI0e0u11P04XqbXooVU6kQnMPcASW96G7W%252BmaKdG4DeM3WWzv%252BO1x%252Fx8JhA877zWgURUb9Axr06PQCEcR7Dabrmj0X59vsXEnJyEnJXk2tmDDoduuzCcpvNJ4G%252BWKSIj5N%252FO2D7OBYb0qmpXMLpsiL1C%252B3g3eNWlCfTaPuwo03m%252Fp7TAd0W16R06PLrClxKvxyHvdpzQhD%252BgEHxU1KvfHMOOD4vq7d5rcWVIpI%252BeM3sjlFWHfYqZe3rUlx3UjQL6YCo7pOXG18oEch7Ruf0e2Uelekpk%252BJ1XwSD%252BT80aTtpB9OtEUnxZXbNuznquJr8sYkxIjPZjtgPrRPQ7DLbM8x80%252BGVkQDIhGj0li7Z9XpLz6uitFyfd81JnQ%252BaS0cieKzEIgPWWsLqYPm96rjSZKGmoBdZNXXN9m8tzxdCUqKr07ZaOZFFm%252BJorXxKUf9C4ugt2wItDqTzsTR6qWLH5hcg5tmQ%253D%253D%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524). (ebay link)

I check all the connections and cannot find an connection problem.

*The red mini LED on the camera raspberry case is on while motion running.*

*I already played around with the resolution and FPS and then came a empty gray picture with a message like "No Video Device found" on it.
Actually i see the broken image icon again now.*

Here is my config file: 
https://gist.github.com/jolution/01c483031a4d8e0229e09a996e5d1ef1

```
stream_port 8081
substream_port 0
webcontrol_port 8080

webcontrol_localhost off
stream_localhost off
```

**/etc/modules** contains:

```
i2c-dev
#snd-bcm2835

bcm2835-v4l2
```

`sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` executed without errors.

`sudo raspi-config` Webcam Interface enabled.

`ls /dev/video*` shows `/dev/video0 /dev/video10 /dev/video11 /dev/video12 /dev/video13 /dev/video14 /dev/video15 /dev/video16`. I have only this one camera wired to the Pi by cable.

**Hardware:**

System: Raspberry Pi Model B Rev2

Camera: [V1-NOIR Rev 1.3](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00GIHO212/ref=pe_386171_38075861_TE_item) (Amazon link)

An Amazon user writes about 25 FPS, while another gives this data:

Specs: 1080p30 (1920x1080), 720p60 (1280x720), 640x480p90

Software:
Motion 4.1(...) latest

OS: Rasbian Lite 32Bit (without Desktop)

SD Card: 3,9GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new but same camera arived and works, so it was the cable or the cam modul v1.3.